# Exponential Generating function

Tags: combinatorics

Use an exponential generating function to determine how many ways there are to make an r-arrangement of pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters with at least one penny and an odd number of quarters.  coins of the same denomination are identical.

Comment: What is an r-arrangement?

Comment: an unordered arrangement

Answer (score 2):

You need exponential generating functions if you want to consider the order of the coins. You have the following generating functions:

- Pennies: At least one, $\frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \ldots = e^z - 1$
- Dimes: Any number, $1 + \frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \ldots = e^z$
- Quarters: An odd number, $\frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \ldots 
                                = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}$

Thus the exponential generating function for $n$ coins is:
$$
(e^z - 1) \cdot e^z \cdot \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}
  = \frac{1}{2} \left( 
                  e^{3 z} - e^{2 z} - e^z + 1
                \right)
$$
We want:
\begin{align}
n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2} \left(
                       e^{3 z} - e^{2 z} - e^z + 1
                     \right)
  &= \frac{n!}{2} \left(
                    \frac{3^n}{n!} - \frac{2^n}{n!} - \frac{1}{n!} + [n = 0]
                  \right) \\
  &= \frac{3^n - 2^n - [n \ne 0]}{2}
\end{align}
(Here $[n = 0]$ is [Iverson's bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), i.e., it is 1 if $n = 0$ and 0 otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

I am going to use regular generating functions instead of exponential ones because I think that is simpler - I'm not sure why the question asks for exponential specifically. I will make series where the exponent $n$ in $x^n$ is the number of cents produced and the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of possible ways to make those $n$ cents out of the coin(s) in question.

With at least one penny there is one way to make 1 cent, 1 way to make 2 cents etc... so the GF is $$(1)x+(1)x^2+\cdots=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ With an odd number of quarters there is one way to make 25 cents, one way to make 75 cents, etc... so the GF is $$(1)x^{25}+(1)x^{75}+(1)x^{125}+\cdots=\frac{x^{25}}{1-x^{50}}$$ With nickels and dimes the GF's are respectively $$1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x^5}$$ and $$1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}$$ We multiply (multiplication gives the total number of possible ways to make some number of cents with all the possible combinations) these functions to get $$\frac{x^{26}}{(1-x)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{50})}$$ So to find the number of ways to make $n$ cents you would take the coefficient of the $x^n$ term in that series: $$\text{#ways to make $n$ pennies}=[x^n]\left(\frac{x^{26}}{(1-x)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{50})}\right)$$

You should probably use a CAS to write that as a power series, or else use partial fractions to decompose it into pieces.